# How can I use datatables with data object?

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, datatables, twig

I am generating a json file to use it later in my datatables:

```
$data = $serializer->serialize($table, 'json');
$file = 'data/data.json';
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

The integration into my datatable:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "{{ absolute_url(asset('data/data.json')) }}",
      "dataSrc": ""
    },
```

Is it possible instead of creating a file, use the `data` object directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ... you can use `data` option in your javascript, like this ... Check https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

```
<?php
// controller
   return $this->render("myTemplate.html.twig", ["data" => $data]);
```

and your template will look ...

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "data": {{ data|json_encode|raw }},
    "columns": [
        ....
    ]
```

**Update**

Since you use special serializer, your code will look

```
<?php
// controller
   $data = $serializer->serialize($table, 'json');
   return $this->render("myTemplate.html.twig", ["data" => $data]);
```

and your twig template must be ...

```
  var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "data": {{ data|raw }},
    "columns": [
      {% for key, value in columns %}
       { "data": "id"},
      {% endfor %}

    ]
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! With this solution, will the performance be as fast as with the file? Or no difference?

Comment: I tested your solution like this `"data": "{{ data|json_encode|raw }}"` but the table is not loaded. In the console there is the error `SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence`. When I write it like this `"data": {{ data|json_encode|raw }},` I get another error `Source map error: request failed with status 404`

Comment: Must be "{{ data|json_encode|raw }}" (without quotes). Check the example in datatables site and put entire javascript code if still not work.

Comment: About your first question, I think that performance is a bit better, but not great difference, unless you have too many requests.

Comment: The problem is this uses the standard php `json_encode` function. In the code question, OP is using the a `serializer`. Might be JMS or the Symfony with particular annotations.

Comment: Oh! @i.am.michiel are right! I updated my answer using serializer and passing data as string.

Comment: This is the code in my controller: https://codeshare.io/29DLeK and this is my javascript code: https://codeshare.io/5vYj17  Like this it is working, I see my table. I replaced it now with your code like this: https://codeshare.io/GL8E1V Now my table is NOT loaded anymore

Comment: Check my update. Since "data" is a string and it's already in Json format, you must render into javascript part of your twig as raw.

Comment: @SilvioQ You mean, performance is bit better with file or without file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

1. Create a route that responds to data/data.json

```
my_data_route_name:
    path: /data/data.json
    controller: App\YourController::yourAction
```

2. Generate your JSON data

```php
$data = []; // Get your data

// You can serialize it and return a Response with the content-type
$json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
return new Response($json, 200, [
    'content-type' => 'application/json'
]);

// or let the symfony serializer handle it.
return $this->json($data);
```

Comment: You can also use `return JsonResponse($data);`

Comment: So this means I cannot just work with `$data` as SilvioQ suggested?